# Limit of ratio of inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: limits, continuity

The question asks to prove/disprove continuity of the following function:
[image]

My approach:

1) Take y = mx.

2) Put x + 2mx = (1+2m) x = kx.

3) Now continue as if k is a constant and how that the final limit depends on k.

Comment: $$2x+4y=2(?)$$ so irrespective of path, the ratio should be $$\dfrac12$$

Comment: Pls elaborate. Didn't understand your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x,y)=\frac{\frac{\sin^{-1}(x+2y)}{x+2y}}{\frac{\tan^{-1} (2x+4y)}{2x+4y}} \frac{x+2y}{2x+4y} \implies \lim_{x,y \rightarrow 0} f(x,y)= \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{\sin^{-1}z}{z}}{\frac{\tan^{-1}{z}}{z}}  \lim_{x,y \rightarrow 0} \frac{x+2y}{2x+4y} =\frac{1}{2}.$$
Here we have used $$\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^{-1}z}{z}=1 = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan^{-1}z}{z}.$$

Comment: @Isham, thanks, you may see my edit.